# Floated elements 100% height dynamic wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have 2 columns within a wrapper. One column is taller than the other. I would like the shorter column given a height of `100%` so that it matches the taller column. All heights are dynamic so can not be defined in pixels.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/L0Lqe4ny/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col1"> short column // not much content </div>
    <div class="col2"> tall columns // lots of content </div>
</div>
```

You will see in the example the red column is taller than the blue column. How do i set the blue column to `100%` height of the wrapper.

I know I can easily do this by defining a height, this isn't an option. I can also do this if I use tables for layout, which I do not want to do. I can also do this by using javascript to get the height from the tall column and then set the height of the smaller column. I would like a CSS only approach though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of jQuery, you can achieve this, have a look https://jsfiddle.net/20d2an0n/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var blue_height = $('.col1').height();
    var red_height = $('.col2').height();
    if(blue_height < red_height)
        $('.col1').height(red_height);
    else
        $('.col2').height(blue_height);
});
```

Comment: Style is not live, meaning if content changes due to resize or dynamically loaded, it'd fail. There should be js library to overcome css limits, it should analyze css get special words and then manage divs.

Comment: That is correct. But the OP asked for static content. Had the OP asked for live content, I would've made the jQuery accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle modified: https://jsfiddle.net/ybywo28c/

Pure CSS solution using flexbox:

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    width: 300px;
}
.col1, .col2 {
    align-self: stretch;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    background: red;
}
.col1 {
    background: blue;
}
```

BTW, if you remove width property from columns and add `flex: 1;` , it will distribute wrapper's width evenly between the columns ;) 
IE 10 requires -ms- prefix, IE8 and 9 unfortunately don't support it at all and among older browsers, syntax may vary - some(for example Android 4.1 and 4.3) use so called "old syntax", if you're curious, check out these pages.

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- http://caniuse.com/#search=flex
- https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/

This is the *most* cross-browser solution you could get, I copy-pasted it from css-tricks.com:

```
.wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
  width: 300px;
}

.col1, .col2 {
  float: left;
  width: 140px;
  background: red;
}

.col1 {
    background: blue;
}
```